# R, Substitute Character in Values Without Affecting Other Values

Tags: r, regex, substitution

In R, I have a character vector which contains numbers, such as:

```
a <- c("1", "1.5", "-2", "3-4.5", "-1", "5-7.5", "3")
```

I want to replace the dash ("-") in the values that contain a range ("3-4.5" and "5-7.5") to another character, say "$".

So in the end I want:

```
a <- c("1", "1.5", "-2", "3$4.5", "-1", "5$7.5", "3")
```

How can I accomplish this?

I wanted to split the values that contain a range by the dash, but doing so would also split the negative numbers which is not what I want.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something like `sub("(\\d)-(\\d)", "\\1$\\2", a)`

Comment: You are good my friend. Although I would have to modify the first argument to accept real numbers instead of just digits.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
a <- c("1", "1.5", "-2", "3$4.5", "-1", "5$7.5", "3")

gsub("([^-]+)(-)(.+)", "\\1$\\3", a)

## [1] "1"     "1.5"   "-2"    "3$4.5" "-1"    "5$7.5" "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use regex lookarounds

```
sub('(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d)', '$', a, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "1"     "1.5"   "-2"    "3$4.5" "-1"    "5$7.5" "3"
```